# Magento: Multi-column dropdown menu

Tags: magento, menu, multiple-columns

I'm using Magento CE 1.6.

Briefly: I found exactly what I'm looking for [here](http://web-experiment.info/webandpeople-custom-menu-extension.html), but it seems like it doesn't work for Magento version 1.6; it's unzipped in the Magento catalog and enabled in the administration panel, but the menu doesn't change at all.

If there's no solution for this extension, is there any free alternative?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: Ensure that the files in the extension goes to the "base" package catalogs; otherwise it will only affect the "default" package.