# cs-cart: free/open source multi column sub menu / drop down

Tags: cs-cart

Is there any free multi-column drop down/sub menu avaialble.

I have find it for magento [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822891/magento-multi-column-dropdown-menu). but I am looking for cs-cart 3.

Here is [one](http://www.p2pdesign.com/shop/multi-column-dropdown.html) which i find, but is not free addon. and I am not sure it will serve my purpose.

Does any one know, if there is any free available? otherwise probabily I have to play with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multi-column already builtin under cs-cart 3. [check this out](http://demo.cs-cart.com/professional/)